# Checking if two arrays are equal - C

Tags: c, arrays

How would I go about checking the equality of two arrays using memcmp?

```
bool array_is_equal(const void *array_one, void *array_two, const size_t elem_size, const size_t elem_count)
```

I have something like this:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < elem_count; i++){
    if(memcmp(array_one, array_two, elem_size) == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    i++;
 }

return false;
```

with elem_size being the number of bytes each array element uses in array one

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If all you care about is binary equality of two array objects, then you don't even need a cycle

```
bool array_is_equal(const void *array_one, void *array_two, 
                    const size_t elem_size, const size_t elem_count)
{
  return memcmp(array_one, array_two, elem_count * elem_size) == 0;
}
```

It is not clear though why array `array_two` is suddenly non-const (while array `array_one` is const). And there's not much point in declaring `elem_size` and `elem_count` as const (aside from fairly cosmetic considerations).

Comment: I receive a seg fault trying this, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Mike Henke: Well, I have no idea why. Apparently you pass invalid parameters to `memcpy`, which can easily trigger a seg fault. But I don't know what you are passing. Show your calling code.

Comment: I actually figured it out! I'm sorry for the late response. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Since your elements can be anything: an int8_t, a pointer, a double pointer on anything; you need a comparison function specific to the type of element stored.

Imagine that your element is a `char *`:The 2 strings are identical, but the 2 addresses are different.

You need to give a pointer function on the comparison function, to your function `array_is_equal`.

For example:

```
bool array_is_equal(const void *array_one, void *array_two, const size_t elem_size, const size_t elem_count, bool (*comparison_fn)(void *, void *));
```

The comparison for strings:

```
bool compare_string(void *str1, void *str2) {
  return !!strcmp((char *) str1, (char *)str2);
}
```

The comparison for a custom struct:
    bool compare_mystruct(void *p1, void *p2) {
      bool ret = true;
      mystryct *s1 = (mystruct *) p1;
      mystryct *s2 = (mystruct *) p2;

```
  if(ret) ret = compare_string(p1->str1, p2->str1);
  if(ret) ret = compare_string(p1->str2, p2->str2);
  if(ret) ret = compare_int(p1->int1, p2->int1);

  return ret;
}
```